# When is a c++ constructor not called?

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit-constructor

I have a situation where no constructor appears to be called:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    class yoyo
    {
        public:
        int i;
        yoyo()
        {
            i = 0;
            cout << "defaultly initialized to 0" << endl;
        }
        yoyo (int j) : i(j)
        {
            cout << "initialized to " << j << endl;
        }
    };

    int i;

    yoyo a;
    cout << "Hello1, i: " << a.i << endl;

    yoyo b(5);
    cout << "Hello2, i: " << b.i << endl;

    yoyo c = b;                                   /* 1 */
    cout << "Hello3, i: " << c.i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
defaultly initialized to 0
Hello1, i: 0
initialized to 5
Hello2, i: 5
Hello3, i: 5
```

(Note: nothing between Hello2 and Hello3)

If I change the program to read as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    class yoyo
    {
        public:
        int i;
        yoyo()
        {
            i = 0;
            cout << "defaultly initialized to 0" << endl;
        }
        yoyo (int j) : i(j)
        {
            cout << "initialized to " << j << endl;
        }
    };

    int i;

    yoyo a;
    cout << "Hello1, i: " << a.i << endl;

    yoyo b(5);
    cout << "Hello2, i: " << b.i << endl;

    yoyo c; c = b;                                  /* 1 */
    cout << "Hello3, i: " << c.i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(The only difference is in he line marked by /* 1 */)

The output now is:

```
defaultly initialized to 0
Hello1, i: 0
initialized to 5
Hello2, i: 5
defaultly initialized to 0
Hello3, i: 5
```

Now there is a constructor call between Hello2 and Hello3. My question is, why is there no (visible) constructor call in the first case?

Comment: You've been missing to track the default copy constructor and `operator=()` implementation.

Answer (score 16):

In the case of

```
yoyo c = b;
```

it's the [*copy constructor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) that is called.

And in the case of

```
yoyo c; c = b;
```

it's the [*copy assignment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29) operator that is called.

If you don't provide any of them, the compiler will generate default versions for you.

---

If you want to create your own copy constructor, it could look like this:

```
yoyo(const yoyo& other)
    : i(other.i)
    { std::cout << "copy constructor initialized\n"; }
```

The copy assignment operator looks like this:

```
yoyo& operator=(const yoyo& other)
    {
        i = other.i;
        return *this;
    }
```

Both of them defined *inside* the class definition of course.

Answer (score 7):

In the first case:

```
yoyo c = b;
```

calls the `copy constructor`, which the compiler generates for you implicitly in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
 yoyo c = b;
```

This is referred to as *copy-initialization*; the compiler-generated copy constructor will be called and `c` will be initialized with that copy. Also, the default constructor of `c` will be called.

```
c = b;
```

Here, this is not initialization, this is assignment. The compiler-generated assignment operator will be invoked on that line.

Answer (score 1):

in your code,

`yoyo c=b` will call copy constructor.if you want to see it being called,you have to define it explicitely.

eg:

```
yoyo(const yoyo& obj)
{
   this->i=obj.i;  cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
}
```

in the second case it will call constructor and then the assignment operator

```
yoyo c; //constructor
c = b;  //assignment operator for which only copying occurs
```

you can overload assignment operator as below

```
yoyo& operator=(yoyo& obj)
{
    i = obj.i;
    cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
}
```